# Android location returns 0.0

Tags: android, location, locationmanager

I'm trying to get the location with the code below, but it's returning 0.0 as the values for both longitude and latitude.

```
public void getLocation(){
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener();

    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0,0, locationListener);
    if(isLocationEnabled(MainActivity.this, lm)){
        Location location = new Location(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        Log.d("LOCATION",String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
        getWeather(location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude());

    }else{
        buildDialog(MainActivity.this);
    }
}
```

However, when I print the location in `MyLocationListener` class, it does return the correct values. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();

        System.out.println("LATITUDE AND LONGITUDE" + latitude + "   " + longitude);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing correct values in onLocationChanged method because the provider created and sent. If you create location object and then use, like this

```
Location location = new Location(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
Log.d("LOCATION",String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
getWeather(location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude());
```

latitude and longitude will be 0.0, because its just created and not set values, check this [Location](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/froyo/location/java/android/location/Location.java#62)

Sorry, i didn't see your second post, you could do like below

```
mLocationManager.requestSingleUpdate("network", new LocationListener() {
@Override public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

     // DO YOUR REST OF WORK HERE
}
@Override public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
@Override public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
@Override public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}}, Looper.myLooper());
```

You must be sure about of having fresh location data, so use location here directly. If you call getLastKnownLocation method without onLocationChanged method being fired, will give old or null data.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to instantiate my `Location` from the `LocationManager`instead of passing in the provider, as reflected in the line below.

```
if(isLocationEnabled(MainActivity.this, lm)){
                Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                Log.d("LOCATION",String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
                getWeather(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
```